# I'm trying to set my bar button image using setBackgroundImage, however, the initial image I set is still there along with the new image?

Tags: xcode, swift

Essentially, I have an ViewMap Icon initially set as the bar button on the top right. I manually set it in IB to be viewMapBtn image (saved in image assets). Now, I want to switch to viewListBtn image once clicked. However, when I do this, the initial viewMapBtn image stays there, and the viewListBtn appears distorted wrapping around the initial image. Why is this doing this, and how can I achieve what I'm looking for?

EDIT:

```
 // Outlet for bar button
 @IBOutlet weak var fbButton: UIBarButtonItem!

// Set Image for bar button
var backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "fb.png")!
fbButton.setBackgroundImage(backImg, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: How are you setting the button's new image?

Comment: I added some example code above. I'm using setBackgroundImage when the action is called. The image get placed, but it's kind of in the same space as the image I set in IB. I want that original image to replaced with the new one programatically

Comment: @PeterLi Have you got any solution?

Comment: @FrequencyMatched not yet. I've had to stick with one icon for now....

Comment: @PeterLi ok..i also tried a lot..but still not getting any solution. Once I've tried for changing bar button `title` and it worked nicely, but in case of `image`..not able to get over the issue.